# Vue - How to use window object inside v-if or components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to use the window object inside a Vue condition:

```
<li v-if="window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition">
    <a href="#">Voice</a>
</li>
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "window" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

How can I work around this error and only display the HTML element if the user's browser has support for the functions `SpeechRecognition`?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/accessing-a-global-object-with-vue/43164/2) in the Vue forums help?

Comment: What vahdet linked. To explain... while in the DOM the scope is "this" (the component) so it is trying to do this.window. instead of window.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can only reference variables in the template that are scoped to the related Vue instance. The warning is saying that your Vue instance doesn't have a property or method named `window` (which isn't what you are trying to refer to anyway).

Just set a data property on the Vue instance (`speechRecognition` or whatever) to the value in your `v-if` statement and then reference that instead of trying to directly access the `window` object from inside your template (which can't be done):

```
data() {
  return {
    speechRecognition: window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition,
  }
}
```

```
<li v-if="speechRecognition">
  <a href="#">Voice</a>
</li>
```

Comment: What if I just declare `window:window` in data?

Comment: @Milano You *could* do that, but it will make every property of the `window` object reactive, which is not super performant.

Answer (score 1):

Define this in your data and use the `window` in the template, hope it will work.

```
data() {
    return {
      window: window
    }
  },
```